# Is mixed ANOVA the correct test for my experiment?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, split-plot

I'm new to statistics and maybe I went a little bit other my head for the experiment design of my bachelor thesis:
I measured the turn angle of people dodging different objects in virtual reality. The virtual rotation of Group A was amplified but for group B it wasn't.
The objects they were dodging had 4 different properties (form, speed, size and incoming direction) and everyone dodged all of the 126 possible conditions of those properties.

I want to check if there are significant differences between the turn angles of group A and group B. I think I need to calculate the mixed ANOVA, with group A and B being between-group and the 4 object properties being within-group. But I am unsure?

Comment: What do you mean that the rotation was **amplified** for one group and not for the other?

Comment: @jmarkov If a subject from group A rotated 45° in the real world, their rotation would be amplified to (e.g.) 50° in the virtual world. My hypothesis is, that the real rotations of group B show no significant difference to the virtual rotations of group A.